# Is my method of proof correct? Suppose $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$. Prove that $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

So I've seen some of the proof strategies on here and I tried the question out by myself but I'm not sure I'm correct as I've seen the proof done with two variables rather than one and I don't quite understand why.

Here is my proof:

> Let us suppose that $A \subseteq B$, which means that for some arbitrary $x$, $\forall x(x \in A \implies x \in B)$. Since $x \in B$, that also means that $x \in \mathcal{P}(B)$. We also have that $x \in A$, so $x \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. Then, $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$ since $x$ is arbitrary. Replacing $B$ with $\mathcal{P}(A)$, we get $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$.

Thanks so much for any and all help!

Comment: I'm assuming that $P(A)$ is the power set of $A$?

Comment: Yes! P(A) is the power set of A, my apologies for not clarifying!

Comment: There are some superfluous elements of your proof. Otherwise, in general $if A \subseteq B$, then we do not necessarily have $x \in A \implies x \in B$. Can you see why? Additionally, what other proof were you looking at?

Comment: I actually don't really understand why that's not necessarily true, do you mind explaining? Because isn't it the definition of subset that if x is in (something) then x is in (something else) ? Here's the proof I looked at after I did mine: https://gyazo.com/3a107083657f8106fdf6d621ca2040f5

Comment: A set $A$ for which $A\subset P(A)$, equivalently, $\forall x\in A\;(x\subset A)$, is called a transitive set.

Comment: @NookLines Take a closer look at the definition of a power set. Let us look at a small case, if $A = \{0, 1\}$, then what is $\mathcal{P}(A)$?

Answer (score 1):

Your last sentence is quite right: the best way to prove that
$$A\subseteq\mathcal P(A)\implies\mathcal P(A)\subseteq\mathcal P(\mathcal P(A))$$
is by proving the more general statement
$$A\subseteq B\implies\mathcal P(A)\subseteq\mathcal P(B).\tag{*}$$

But your proof of $(*)$ is incorrect.  Towards a correct proof of $(*)$ note that the statement
"$\mathcal P(A)\subseteq\mathcal P(B)$" means "every element of $\mathcal P(A)$ is an element of $\mathcal P(B)",$ which in turn means "every subset of $A$ is a subset of $B."$ Your task, then, is to prove that, if $A\subseteq B$ and $X\subseteq A,$ then $X\subseteq B.$

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is incorrect. In your proof you state that $x \in B$ and therefore $x \in \mathcal{P}(B)$ but this is not necessarily true (consider any $x$ that is not a set).

Comment: I have no idea what the two commenters above were thinking; this is without a doubt an answer to the question (though perhaps not the most thorough possible answer, as OP's argument contains more fundamental flaws than the one pointed out here).

Comment: Yeah @EricWofsey, not sure what they are saying. The question clearly states "Is my proof method correct?" which I answered and backed up with an example. I do agree that it could have been more thorough but I certainly wasn't critiquing or requesting clarification as Stefan suggested.